# 2D animation framework for windows store apps

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-store

I am trying to develop a user interface which involves creating train sets on the canvas. I am planning to create this as a windows store app. I have some experience in Silverlight and xaml. I am planning to make my app in C# and Xaml.

I have done some research on the web and I could not find any decent framework which support following animations and UI activities:

1. Drag and drop controls
2. Snapping of controls
3. Reordering snapped controls
4. Drop-shadow effects for control

I know how to di all these in Silverlight world but the windows store xaml put some limitations. Could anyone suggest some framework or perhaps code samples that could be useful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview.aspx) control offers drag and drop, snapping and reordering of items right out of the box.

Comment: Thank you Brandon for Answer